# 301 htaccess redirection from old permalinks to new permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I recently transferred my Blogger blog to WordPress, and I want to redirect old Blogger permalinks to the new site.

Old:

```
http://sitename.com/2012/04/my-post-url.html
```

To new:

```
http://sitename.com/my-post-url/
```

I've tried following .htaccess code. It removes years and months, but doesn't remove `.html`. Can anyone tell me how to get `/` instead of `.html` at the end of the link?

Any modification for the following code?

```
RedirectMatch 301 /\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 /\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)\.html http://mydomain.com/$1
```

That should do the trick. :)