# How to redirect URL's from old CMS to the new one? Need specific RewriteMatch directive

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

My old site was built on Joomla+Virtuemart engine, now i've created new one on Wordpress.
My problem is Google's index - many visitors still coming by old URL's (`http://example.com/component/virtuemart/123.html`, etc).
I want to make **301 Redirect** on new site's frontpage (`http://example.com`), if user arrives from old URL, that contains this part:

> /component/virtuemart/*any_url*

.
I'm not very expirienced in regular expressions, so please help me to write working expression for my htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_alias, you might use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/component/virtuemart.* http://mydomain.com/newaddress
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/virtuemart.* /newaddress [L,R=301]
```

I based those on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10009239/1578604).